# Android database query with IN AND

Tags: android, sqlite

I have problem with this query, I get no data for it, is my syntax correct?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append(MyTable.FIELDONE)
    .append(" in (?, ?, ?) AND ").append(MyTable.FIELDTWO)
    .append("=? AND ").append(MyTable.FIELDTHREE).append("=?");

String[] args = new String[] { "1", "2", "0", "0", "0" };

Cursor cCategory = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
    MyTable.CONTENT_URI, MyTable.PROJECTION, sb.toString(), args,
    MyTable.SORT_ORDER);
```

Comment: yes, have you tried running it against your sqlite database on your pc?

Comment: No, could You tell how?

Comment: Do you get an error or a null ResultSet.  If you're not getting an error, your SQL syntax is fine.

Comment: @Meryl it depends on your development environment. If you have root access, you can run that in a database manager on the device directly. If not you need to copy the database to your sd card and download it on your pc to run it then.

Comment: If you're using an emulator, you don't need root access. Using the DDMS perspective, select the File Explorer tab then go to /data/data/your.package.name/databases and pull the database from the device to your PC. Then Google 'sqlite browser' for something suitable to read it and then run the SQL from there to verify the output.

Comment: Query is fine as @WarrenFaith said, I had bug in other part of code. Thanks for help guys.